# Prove: f is uniform continuity implies bounded derivative

Tags: calculus, functions

Show a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ who is uniformly continuous implies derivate is bounded.
any idea
thanks

Comment: This is false.  A function can be uniformly continuous even if there are places where its derivative is arbitrarily big; you just need those big values of the derivative to be confined to sufficiently short intervals.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Isn't this part of the reason why Weirstrass' function is nowhere differentiable?

Comment: @gary There are several ways to see that Weierstrass's function is nowhere differentiable, and my comment may be involved in some of those ways.  But counterexamples for this question can be considerably easier than the Weierstrass function.  Also, the OP requires the function  to be everywhere differentiable --- at least that's what I think "who is derivate in all $\mathbb R$" is intended to mean.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks for the answer, I meant that the derivative fails to exist because it goes to infinity at some points.

Comment: @AndreasBlass , so in my university class , and homework was show "f:R->R ,  funcion derivable, probar que f es uniformemente continua si y solo si su derivada esta acotada" . i never can probe this, so was false...

Comment: @user89940: Se traduce: Show a differentiable function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is uniformly continuous iff its derivative is bounded.

Comment: @user89940: Puede editarla o si quieres yo la puedo editar.